Is there a faster way to crawl a predefined list of URLs with scrapy when having to authenticate first?
I have two scrapy Spiders:

Spider 1 crawls a list of product links (~10000) and saves them to a csv file using a feed. It doesn't visit each of those links, only the categories (with multiple pages). This Spider rarely needs to run, so speed is not an issue here.
Spider 2 visits each of those links and extracts some product information, also saving to a csv feed. This needs to run at least once a day, so speed is crucial.

As both visit the same website (just different subpages), their structure is similar. Both need to authenticate first (multi-step authentication), which is why I can't just have all the links that they need to crawl in start_urls. I don't have a static authentication token, I need to simulate the actual user login. However, even though they're extremely similar, Spider 1 crawls about 500 pages per minute and Spider 2 only about 50 pages per minute, which is way to slow.
The only key difference is how they "discover" the pages that they need to crawl:

Spider 1 starts with a small list and then discovers the other pages one by one
Spider 2 reads a large predefined list from a file and then just loops over the pages to crawl them

Since both also don't really do any heavy processing of the crawled pages, my guess was that running the pages in a loop like in Spider 2 (method after_2nd_step) prevents scrapy from properly crawling them asynchronously, but I have no clue if that's really the case. I'm using scrapy runspider file.py if that's important.
Another assumption I had, is that the website itself takes longer to load the product info pages for whatever reason. I didn't however find a way to see some data on that, like average page load times for an execution.
So my question is the following: Why is spider 2 10x slower than Spider 1, even though it's running on the same machine, crawling the same website? Is there a faster way to crawl the long predefined list of URLs in Spider 2? If the issue isn't obvious from my code, is there a good way to analyze the time needed for the page to load?
Here's my code for both of them, I did anonymize some sensitive parts, be assured that the original is valid python code. I tried to keep most of it, since there might be an issue in something that seems irrelevant to me:
# Spider 1
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

from product_pages import PRODUKTSEITEN # a list of ~27 predefined URLs for all the categories

class ProductLinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_name'
    start_urls = ['URL to login page']

    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'path\\product_links.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'overwrite': True,
            },
        },
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # First, we handle the login form
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='loginForm',
            formdata={
                #entering password and username
            },
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # Check for login success by verifying the response content
        if "Your User ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again" in response.text:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
        # 2nd login step
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formxpath='//form[@action="/lorem ipsum"]',
            formdata={
                # Formdata is filled in
            },
            callback=self.after_2nd_step
        )

    def after_2nd_step(self, response):
        for page in PRODUKTSEITEN:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                page+"?sort=asc&q=%3Arelevance#&page=0",
                callback=self.parse_products_list_page,
                cb_kwargs=dict(url_without_page=page+"?sort=asc&q=%3Arelevance", page=0)
                )

    def parse_products_list_page(self, response: TextResponse, url_without_page: str, page: int):
        product_links = response.css('a css selector to get the links').getall()

        if There is another page:
            # Checks if there is another page, and requests it next
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url_without_page + f"&page={page+1}",
                callback=self.parse_products_list_page,
                cb_kwargs=dict(url_without_page=url_without_page, page=page+1)
            )

        for link in product_links:
            yield {"url": link}

And for the second Spider:
# Spider 2
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import TextResponse


class ProductInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lorem ipsum'
    start_urls = ['login page']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'path\\product_info_added_2.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'overwrite': True,
            },
        },
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # First, we handle the login form
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='loginForm',
            formdata={
                # Enter username and password
            },
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # Check for login success by verifying the response content
        if "Your User ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again" in response.text:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formxpath='//form[@action="/lorem ipsum"]',
            formdata={
                # Enter the same data as in the first Spider
            },
            callback=self.after_2nd_step
        )

    def after_2nd_step(self, response):
        with open(r"path\product_links.csv", "r") as file:
            # HERE is the only key difference
            lines = file.readlines()
            product_links = lines[1:]
        for link in product_links:
            yield scrapy.Request("domain"+link, callback=self.parse_product_page) 
        
    def parse_product_page(self, response):
        # extract some info about the product using 4  different css selectors to get the data
        yield {Some of the extracted info, 6 columns}


You can try to use Scrapy's start_requests() method to send authenticated requests to each URL in your predefined list. Simply include your login credentials in the headers or cookies within each request.
def start_requests(self):
for url in urls_list:
    yield scrapy.Request(url, cookies={'auth_token': 'your_token'})


Thanks for your input, but I don't have a static authentication token, I need to actually simulate the user login to start a session, which is why this wouldn't work.
